# accessing elements in objectified XML

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml string below that I've turned into an object using

```
$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, "ASCII");
$obj = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
```

The structure of obj is perfectly matching the xml. However trying to get an array of sets without the parent "set" node is causing me issues.
I do

```
foreach($obj->group as $currentGroup)
{
```

From inside here if I do ***$currentGroup->sets*** I then see a **set** node with numbering under it, 0 and 1, and under it the structure of the subtest.
My problem is it I try to do $currentGroup->sets->set (to try to get an array of sets without the parent then I get the first set automatically and none of the others ones. 
[image]

```
<global>
    <group name="bce">
        <sets>
            <set name="a">
                <subsets>
                    <subset name="bla"/>
                    <subset name="bla2"/>
                    <subset name="bla3"/>
                </subsets>
            </set>
            <set name="b" />
                <subsets>
                    <subset name="bla"/>
                    <subset name="bla2"/>
                    <subset name="bla3"/>
                </subsets>
            </set>
            <set name="c" />
                <subsets>
                    <subset name="bla"/>
                    <subset name="bla2"/>
                    <subset name="bla3"/>
                </subsets>
            </set>
            <set name="d" />
                <subsets>
                    <subset name="bla"/>
                    <subset name="bla2"/>
                    <subset name="bla3"/>
                </subsets>
            </set>
        </subgroupones>
    </group>
    <group name="ert">
        <sets>
            <set name="aa">
                <subsets>
                    <subset name="bla"/>
                    <subset name="bla2"/>
                    <subset name="bla3"/>
                </subsets>
            </set>
            <set name="bb" />
                <subsets>
                    <subset name="bla"/>
                    <subset name="bla2"/>
                    <subset name="bla3"/>
                </subsets>
            </set>
        </subgroupones>
    </group>
</global>
```

Comment: Seems like you're missing a closed `</sets>` tag. Not sure if that's the issue. Just noticed it. Also the closed tag `</subgroupones>` does not have an open tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want an array of the **set** nodes?  Should be `$currentGroup->sets->children()` unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Perfect thanks alot, that is what I was looking for. Is there a way from that same line to automatically select the first node?

Comment: Sadly PHP doesn't let you dereference arrays from functions that return them, you have to store the value in an variable first. See [this old thread](http://marc.info/?l=php-general&m=120422624624319&w=2) for more info.  However, if all you want is the first element and not the set, you can simply use `$currentGroup->sets->set[0]`.